# Google Places Autocomplete - how to remove permanently closed places?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches) autocomplete library, and I've noticed it returns places that are permanently closed (which is not useful for my users).

I know they're permanently closed because there's a property on the place details that says "place.permanently_closed = true"

```
 var view = {};
 view.placesAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#venue').get()[0], {});
 google.maps.event.addListener(view.placesAutocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      view.place = view.placesAutocomplete.getPlace();
      // view.place.permanently_closed equals true for some results! not helpful...
 });
```

How can I can prevent these permanently closed venues from showing up in my autocomplete results? Or filter them out?

**UPDATE:**
Anyone who happens upon this, I finally concluded there's no way to do it except looping through the place results in javascript and pulling out the results manually, or warning the user that the place is closed based on checking the place.permanently_closed variable then showing a message.

Comment: Where is the property *place.permanently_closed* documented? Can you provide a link?

Comment: There's a place called Venice Grind that's actually a Coffee Shop, however Google only knows about the old art gallery that the shop has since replaced: https://plus.google.com/116168257615113604097/about?gl=us&hl=en

Comment: That doesn't answer my question :-) Where did you see **documentation** for an object property called .permanently_closed?

Comment: Ah sorry - I didn't see documentation, I just noticed it in the returned JSON object. view.placesAutocomplete.getPlace() has a "permanently_closed : true" field on it when I look at it in the Chrome JS debugger

Comment: Hi. Any idea how to loop through the place results in javascript and remove results manually ? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There currently doesn't exists any method to filter the suggestions(you can't even get access to the suggestions, except when you select one).

The only way I see so far is to request a place(without an autocomplete) and build the autocomplete-box on your own.